# How come I can't access $scope.map in my directive-controller?

Tags: angularjs

I have a directive that generates a google map:

```
directive('gMap', function(googleMaps){
return{
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        transclude: true,
        template: "<div ng-transclude></div>",
        scope: true,
        link: function(scope, element, attrs){
            scope.$on('location', function(){
                //här ska den recentreras
            })

            //create the map
            var center = googleMaps.makePosition(attrs.centerlat, attrs.centerlong)
            //update map on load
            var options = googleMaps.setMapOptions(center, attrs.zoom);
            scope.map = googleMaps.createMap(options, attrs.id)
            //googleMaps.addMarker(map, center,'Hello')

        },
        controller: ['$scope', function($scope) {
            console.log($scope);
        }]
    };
}).
```

When I do `console.log($scope)`, it outputs an object containing the node map.
When I try to `console.log($scope.map)` it outputs `undefinded`, why?

Comment: strangely, this works if I wrap it in $timeout: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you have a scope, when you call `console.log()`, but the `map` is not created yet, since the controller is instantiated before the pre-linking phase.

Assuming you use Chrome, `console.log()` can produce an "updated" view, that does **not** reflect the state of an object at the time `console.log()` is called. But `undefined` cannot be updated, of course.

Comment: I see, is there a best practie for dealing with this? I need to do it after the map-object is created, because I use it in a child-node.

Comment: @KristofferNolgren If you need `map` in the controller constructor the `$timeout` is a perfect solution.

Comment: @KristofferNolgren That's because it is one ;) The question is why the controller function needs access to the map in the first place. Creating the map directly in the controller function might be a feasible alternative for you. You can access the attributes of the element by injecting `$attrs`.